# Would an offer for sale that originates in the US on the phone with someone in Japan create a preAIA 102(b) bar?

Tags: on-sale, pre-aia, 102b

If person A in the United States calls a member of the public in a foreign country and offers to sell a product 14 months prior to A filing a nonprovisional application for a utility patent, would that be a 102(b) bar or would that be considered a sale that is not in the United States?

Comment: Is this an application considered pre-AIA or under the AIA?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite preAIA

Comment: I read about a case called Group One vs Hallmark Cards were the federal circuit apparently drew a line that it had to be an offer for sale under the UCC.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Would a sale originated by phone to someone in a foreign country start the clock for 102(b)?

Comment: I posted as an informative comment rather than an answer because I don't know the answer. My guess is that it does start the clock. If you don't think it does and file I would put mention of this in an IDS.